# How to make 2 columns of divs with 3 rows in each, centered inside another box with a gap between the 2 columns

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make 2 columns of divs with 3 rows in each, centered inside another box but I want to use `flex` as it shouldn't require the extra outer div that I've got.

**Unfortunately, I need the first 3 divs on the left and the last 3 divs on the right and NOT every second on the right and I'm unable to alter the underlying HTML, I can only change the CSS.**

This is what I've gotten so far which displays correctly with `floats` however it does every second div and not the first 3 and last 3 in separate columns. I'm also not sure how to make it work with `flex`: https://jsfiddle.net/yL521qan/

HTML:

```
<div id="outer-wrapper">
  <div id="box-wrapper">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
    <div>d</div>
    <div>e</div>
    <div>f</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer-wrapper { display: table; width: 100%; }
#box-wrapper { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; height: 200px; width: 100%; border: 1px solid #000; overflow: auto; }
#box-wrapper > div { display: block; border: 1px solid green; width: 30%; }
#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(2n+1) { float: left; clear: left; }
#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(2n) { float: right; clear: right; }
#box-wrapper > div:last-child:after { content: ""; overflow: auto; }
```

I want it to look exactly like my `floats` JSFiddle but instead with A, B and C on the left and D, E and F on the right. Any ideas? I've tried using `align-self: flex-start;` and `align-self: flex-end;` while wrapping it in a `flex-direction: column;` but it puts a new line on each line and doesn't vertically align the right column with the left.

In my project, I'm unable to modify the HTML so it needs to only contain the `#box-wrapper` and the `divs` inside of it. The `#outer-wrapper` was only added for proof of concept of what I want.

Current flex implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/zmsnuj7d/

Any ideas at all would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: why not try grid?

Comment: that's true, grid would probably work pretty well in this case, still interested in a flex solution to see if it's possible with flex or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)?

It would allow you to alter the render order, which should get you what you need. Here are two examples. One using flex and the other using grid. There's probably a less verbose way to implement the CSS, but this is just proof-of-concept. The grid version is arguably preferable if you're targeting browsers that support it, because it will keep the divs lined up even if the content height varies.

[Here's one using flex](https://jsfiddle.net/rayhatfield/504b82h6/)

```css
#box-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#box-wrapper > div {
  flex: 1 1 calc(50% - 2px);
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* a */
#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(1) {
  order: 0;
}

/* d */
#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(4) {
  order: 1;
}

/* b */
#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}

/* e */
#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(5) {
  order: 3;
}

/* c */
#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(3) {
  order: 4;
}

/* e */
#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(6) {
  order: 5;
}
```

```html
  <div id="box-wrapper">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
    <div>d</div>
    <div>e</div>
    <div>f</div>
  </div>
```

[Here's one using grid](https://jsfiddle.net/rayhatfield/uwsmodk4/1/)

```css
#box-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 8px;
}

#box-wrapper > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(1n + 4) {
  grid-column: 3;
}

/* a */
#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(1) {
  order: 0;
}

/* d */
#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(4) {
  order: 1;
}

/* b */
#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}

/* e */
#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(5) {
  order: 3;
}

/* c */
#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(3) {
  order: 4;
}

/* e */
#box-wrapper > div:nth-child(6) {
  order: 5;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-wrapper">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
    <div>d</div>
    <div>e</div>
    <div>f</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's true, that would definitely be useful but I'm still not sure how to get the 2 columns aligned so the tops are in alignment with flex and order wouldn't work with the floats.

Comment: Ugh. I had this working but lost it when jsfiddle redirected me to log in.

Comment: Part of the problem is that the divs aren't very wide in width and they can't take up the full 50% width like your example, it needs that big gap like in my original example.

Comment: I updated the grid example to include a middle gap.

Comment: That grid solution works nicely, I've also fixed out how to do it with flex as well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the solution with using `flex` as well. You need to use `break-after: always;` for each second div.

CSS:

```
/* left column */
#box-wrapper>div:nth-child(1) {
  order: 0;
}

#box-wrapper>div:nth-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}

#box-wrapper>div:nth-child(3) {
  order: 4;
}

/* right column */
#box-wrapper>div:nth-child(4) {
  order: 1;
  break-after: always;
}

#box-wrapper>div:nth-child(5) {
  order: 3;
  break-after: always;
}

#box-wrapper>div:nth-child(6) {
  order: 5;
  break-after: always;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9a601kz4/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting ?

Ive done it without using float

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  border: solid red;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.right {
  width: 25vw;
  border: solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left {
  border: solid red;
  width: 25vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  border: solid green;
}
.child:first-child{
margin-top:100px;
}
.child:last-child{
margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code however I'm unable to alter the HTML as the content is dynamic so I'm unable to wrap the divs in another class like right or left unfortunately.

Comment: @FirstLegion so u need to imlement this without left and right classes ? but use flex ?

Comment: @FirstLegion in your question you have mentioned about two columns. And is it ok if half of the child are at left and the rest are at right ?

Comment: I meant visually displayed as 2 columns, yea that would be fine with half on the left and half on the right